# Grouping values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that contain 3 columns, Id, Stage, Status. I would like to change that value based on the condition: if for the same ID, the stage changed, then change the status to 1. If another occurrence of the same id happened, stage is still same then change status back to 0.

Thanks !!

Comment: Is it feasible to do this with `for` loops? Usually the best way to create a transformed column in a `df` is with `map`, but in this case it will be difficult to express the desired operations into a single `lambda` function (although not necessarily impossible). Looping over `df` can be very time consuming, so this may only be an option if the `df` isn't very large.

Comment: Do you only need the final result for each ID or also all intermediate results?

Comment: We can use anything, as a first result I wish to have the first result without the intermediate. If it is doable to do the intermediate it will much better. But my main concern is to have this Status column changing its values if the Stage is changing for a certain ID.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the *Period* column, you can calculate the result with two (nested) *groupby*s:

```
df["Period"] = (df.groupby("ID", group_keys=False)
                  # use the common diff.cumsum pattern to calculate the group variable here
                  .apply(lambda g: g.groupby(by = (g.Stage.diff() != 0).cumsum())
                                    .cumcount() * 30))
df
```

[image]

Comment: It seems my pc having hard time with the groupby, when I get any result I'll inform you.

Comment: I've got this raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")

Comment: You may have duplicated index in your data frame, if you don't have to keep them, try `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` before the `groupby`.

Answer (score 1):

The status column can be obtained this way:

```
df.groupby('ID').diff().Stage.fillna(0).ne(0)
Out[86]: 
4     False
10     True
0     False
2      True
3      True
5      True
7     False
8     False
9      True
1     False
6     False
Name: Stage, dtype: bool
```

Comment: this will not work if the stage is changing continuously

Comment: @Shijo true, answer amended

Comment: That's smart :)

Answer (score 0):

You needs to sort on column ID and then use [np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)  and [df.shift()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to find the right status.

```
df=df.sort_values('ID')

df['Status']=np.where(((df.ID.shift()==df.ID) & (df.Stage.shift()<>df.Stage)),1,0)
```

output

```
    ID  Stage  Status  
4   45      2       0  
10  45      3       1  
0   50      4       0  
2   50      5       1  
3   50      6       1  
5   50      4       1  
7   50      4       0  
8   50      4       0  
9   50      5       1  
1   55      3       0  
6   55      3       0
```

Comment: df['Status']=np.where(((df.ID.shift()==df.ID) & (df.Stage.shift()<>df.Stage)),1,0)
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: not sure what's happening, its running fine on my machine